# Golang Unmarshall specific object in nested JSON

Tags: arrays, json, go, unmarshalling

what is the best practice to unmarshall a specific part of a large JSON with static property names in GO?

my JSON map looks like

```
{
    "top_view" : {
       "@self" : "https://generic.com",
           "graph" : {
              "nodes" : [ { } ],
              "relations" : [ { } ]
                     },
         "view_status" : {}
                 }
}
```

and I only need to retrieve the Nodes array

Here is what I got so far,

https://play.golang.org/p/btfRojEGqUu

I only know how to unmarshall the Nodes part, but I don't know how to tell Go to start unmarshalling only that object, so the code won't work if I feed the entire JSON tree.
Please advise, thanks!

Comment: I don't think this would be possible, since the tree has to be parsed from top down. You can however do the other way round, ie keeping `nodes` key marshelled

Comment: Declare Go types with the minimal structure required to get the part you want. Unmarshal the JSON document  and pick out the part you want.  `var data = struct { TopView struct { Self struct { Graph Graph } \`json:"@self"\` } \`json:"top_view"\` }`

Comment: In my opinion the best way is to just unmarshal into a matching structure and then ignore the undesired parts. For example: https://play.golang.org/p/y_9IdVpZdqW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:
Define a struct that shows the path to the Node. You can skip the members in the JSON that are not interesting. For example:

```
type Whole struct {
    TopView struct {
        Self  string `json:"@self"`
        Graph struct {
            Nodes []Node `json:"nodes"`
        } `json:"graph"`
    } `json:"top_view"`
}
```

Then marshal out the Node

```
var whole Whole

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonResp), &whole)
```

Here is the working code :
https://play.golang.org/p/5WvPocce_vh

Comment: thank you, I loved this elegant solution!

Answer (score -1):

You can unmarshall any JSON data without any concrete type defined in the `go` code. An use `type assertion` and `type switch` to drill-down the data just unmarshlled.

Below is working example of your problem using above mentioned concepts. You may need to further refine this basis your requirement, but basic concept remains the same:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    jsonResponse := `{
        "top_view" : {
           "@self" : "https://generic.com",
               "graph" : {
                  "nodes" : [ {
                    "@self" : "https://generic.com:443",
                    "id" : "1;;45d554600be28ee49c99d26e536225ea;;461ff354437881f6b5973d4af366b91c;;4c0f2cc8e29a4fe09240b2a0c311508d",
                    "ci" : {
                       "id" : "4c0f2cc8e29a4fe09240b2a0c311508d",
                       "name" : "NOICE",
                       "type" : "ci_collection",
                       "type_label" : "CiCollection",
                       "icon" : "/logical_group_32.svg"
                    },
                    "has_children" : true
                 }, {
                    "@self" : "https://generic.com:443hjkhk",
                    "id" : "1;;45d554600be28ee49c99d26e536225ea;;4e22910a478bf6939aed36fef22dc79e;;4a7788eeecbbeee3a8bb3189ba67f269",
                    "ci" : {
                       "id" : "4a7788eeecbbeee3a8bb3189ba67f269",
                       "name" : "NOTNOICE",
                       "type" : "ci_collection",
                       "type_label" : "CiCollection",
                       "icon" : "/logical_group_32.svg"
                    },
                    "has_children" : true
                 }, {
                    "@self" : "https://generic.com:443/fghfgh",
                    "id" : "1;;45d554600be28ee49c99d26e536225ea;;461ff354437881f6b5973d4af366b91c;;4c0f2cc8e29a4fe09240b2a0c311508d;;40b8b314821d01ac874f7209c228ab8f",
                    "ci" : {
                       "id" : "40b8b314821d01ac874f7209c228ab8f",
                       "name" : "NOICE",
                       "type" : "ci_collection",
                       "type_label" : "CiCollection",
                       "icon" : "/logical_group_32.svg"
                    },
                    "has_children" : true
                 }, {
                    "@self" : "https://generic.com:443/gfhgh",
                    "id" : "1;;45d554600be28ee49c99d26e536225ea;;4a208e0deee006668bb3cfab6541a869;;4bd30d48bc1c81b398e17435ba519f2d;;4a1c671cefd3b5b9931b4312382ff2e4",
                    "ci" : {
                       "id" : "4a1c671cefd3b5b9931b4312382ff2e4",
                       "name" : "AAA",
                       "type" : "ci_collection",
                       "type_label" : "CiCollection",
                       "icon" : "/logical_group_32.svg"
                    },
                    "has_children" : true
                 } ],
                  "relations" : [ { } ]
                         },
             "view_status" : {}
                     }
    }`

    var res interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonResponse), &res)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    parseArbitoryJSONObject(res)
}

func parseArbitoryJSONObject(jsonObject interface{}) {
    data := jsonObject.(map[string]interface{})

    for k, v := range data {
        switch val := v.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println(k, "is string:", val)
        case float64:
            fmt.Println(k, "is float64", val)
        case bool:
            fmt.Println(k, "is boolean", val)
        case []interface{}:
            fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
            for i, u := range val {
                fmt.Println(i, u)
            }
        case map[string]interface{}:
            fmt.Println(k, "is an map[string]interface{}:")
            parseArbitoryJSONObject(val)
        default:
            fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
        }
    }
}
```

Here the `json.Unmarshal` is using `empty interface` which can hold any value. And function `parseArbitoryJSONObject()` is using `type assertion` to facilitate value extraction from the unmarshlled data.

The `type switch` is where you may need to further put or modify logic to get the desired item from the unmarshlled JSON object.

below is the go-playground code snippet link for your reference:

https://play.golang.org/p/VUJsSXxSfVG